# AppEngine Datastore Timeout Error thrown before 30s limit reached

Tags: google-app-engine

Using AppEngine Go, I'm consistently seeing this error when reading from tables on the order of 40k entities:

API error 5 (datastore_v3: TIMEOUT): The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.

This is happening within 400ms of the query firing.

Is there something else that could cause this error besides hitting a limit on the wall clock?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Turns out each individual API call has a 5s timeout. If you need more time, you can wrap your context like so:

```
ctx := appengine.Timeout(appengine.NewContext(req), 30*time.Second)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is deprecated, for newer versions of Go, see the README here:

> appengine.Timeout has been removed. Use context.WithTimeout instead.

https://github.com/golang/appengine#2-update-code-using-deprecated-removed-or-modified-apis

Making it easier for everyone, here is an example we're using:

```go
timeout := 300 * time.Second
c, cFunc := context.WithTimeout(c, timeout)
```

The important part is to call the `cFunc()` method after your context is no-longer required, as to avoid context leaks.

Enjoy.