# appengine datastore index has no entries

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I was trying out a couple of things on golang and google appengine datastore.  In some cases indexes seem to be created as shown in the image.  In other cases it says 'Serving', but there are seemingly no entries. Because of this I also get an error in the logs:

`API error 5 (datastore_v3: TIMEOUT): The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.`

[image: screenshot of empty datastore index]

As far as I can see, there doesn't seem to be any significant difference between the various indexes I'm trying.  Is there any reason why some indexes would be served but others not?

Comment: Meanwhile I deleted unused indexes.  Also the one that I am interested in (CustomerCode & Timestamp).  Then added it back again.  Still the same, 
"- - Serving" and timeout errors in code.

Comment: Looks like the problem was elsewhere.  This apparently has to do with a timeout rather than the index itself.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827362/appengine-datastore-timeout-error-thrown-before-30s-limit-reached